# Why is my Text Input getting activated only at the width of PlaceHolder?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building an `Android` specific app using `React-Native`.

In this app I am trying to build a custom `TextInputField` which can be re-used. This is my Custom Function Component

```
function AppTextInput({ icon, ...otherProps }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {icon && (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name={icon}
          size={20}
          color={colors.medium}
          style={styles.icon}
        />
      )}
      <TextInput style={customStyles.text} {...otherProps} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: colors.light,
    borderRadius: 25,
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "100%",
    padding: 15,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  icon: {
    margin: 3,
    marginRight: 7,
  },
});

export default AppTextInput;
```

I call this component from my `App.js` like so

```
<AppTextInput
  autoCapitalize="none"
  autoCorrect={false}
  icon="email"
  keyboardType="email-address"
  placeholder="Email"
/>
```

The issue here is, this field is set-to focus only when I touch on the width occupied by `placeholder` text and not the entire text field. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple solution,

```
<TextInput style={[customStyles.text, { flex: 1 }]} {...otherProps} />
```

Answer (score 2):

The focus effect will only happen when you press on the text input itself, and if you give it a background color you will find out that your text input is small and the pressable area that will trigger the focus effect is small (Only the text input area)

**The solution** is to make the whole View that contain the input and the icon trigger the focus via useRef like this:

```
export default function AppTextInput({ icon, ...otherProps }) {
  const textInput = React.useRef(null);
  

  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <Pressable style={styles.container} onPress={handleClick}>
      {icon && 
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name={icon}
          size={20}
          color={colors.medium}
          style={styles.icon}
        />}
      <TextInput ref={textInput} {...otherProps} />
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

Also replace the View with Pressable to be able to use onPress.